# "The box of candies" or "The box of THE candies"

Tags: comparisons

I understand that

> "Look on the table. Take the box of candies."

is ok. But is this ok?

> "Take the box of **the** candies."

If so, is there any difference?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It's not related. The only thing the questions have in common are the words 'box of'. That question is about whether 'a box of  X' can be called empty since it has X in it. This question is about use of the definite article.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but it's certainly related. The discussion there examined whether 'box of matches' implied matches being present; OP's question here about possible differences involves this argument.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - If that were true then it could make for a very interesting and illuminating answer.  However I don't see it. Even if the expression 'the box of the candies' worked in English, it would give no indication of  whether there were any candies inside it  at the time of speaking. Nevertheless, I'm still interested in your reasoning, could you explain further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Take the box of the candies* is a very unlikely thing to say in English. The only meaning I can ascribe to it is that there are several boxes on the table, and one of them has a kind of candy which we have already talked about, so we both know what candies I mean by "the candies", and I am directing you take that box, rather than any of the other boxes, which might have other candies or anything else.

But even then, I think I'm more likely to say *Take the box with the candies*.

In most cases, if I heard this I would assume it was said by somebody who was not an English speaker. The meaning that Frederic gives would not occur to me unless there was some very strong context suggesting it.

Comment: So in general the question was about "the after of". And I understand that "the after of" is rarely used. It "separates" second noun from first (or from other "first nouns").

Comment: There is no problem with 'of the'. For example:  "*here is the dinner, and I must beg of you to  **take the top of the table**, because the dinner is of your providing.*"  Great Expectations By Charles Dickens. http://www.victorianlondon.org/etexts/dickens/great_expectations-0022.shtml   The phrase that causes the problem is, "the box of the candies".

Comment: @Colin - I agree with everything you say in this answer. However you haven't said *why* 'the box of the candies' doesn't work. The grammatical structure isn't forbidden -- see my comment immediately  above. Do you have any thoughts on this? I'd be interested and it would definitely improve the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK. Good question. It turns on the kind of "of", for sure. If we were talking about some special candies, that came in their own craftsman-made box, then _the box of the candies_ would be possible, though awkward. But I'm having trouble characterising it.